# Unable to pass variable to other class

Tags: java

I am trying to create a timer that will display inside of JLabel, I know that the code itself works as I tried it with System.out.println, but I can't figure out how to make the other class see the JLabel.

I am a complete beginner and have been trying to figure it out since yesterday morning. I tried googling it, looking at video tutorials, reading tutorials, finding similar issues, using getter and setter, using different variables. Nothing helped. I do realize that it's very easy problem but I can't figure it out, I would really appreciate any form of help.

**Class containing Timer code:**

```
    package Timernew;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class newTimer {    

    Timer timer = null;
    int counter = 5;
    int delay = 1500;

//method that will be called when the timer needs to start

    public void startTimer() {


        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

                if (counter == 0) {
                    timer.stop();

                    lblTimerE.setText("Time up");
                } else {
                    lblTimerE.setText("Wait for " + counter + " sec");
                    counter--;
                }
            }
        };  //end of action performed statement

        timer = new Timer(delay, action);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start(); //this will start the timer


    } //end of method

}
```

**Class containing JLabel and trigger button:**

```
    package Timernew;

import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class Easy extends javax.swing.JFrame {

         newTimer time = new newTimer();




    /**
     * Creates new form Easy
     */
    public Easy() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        lblTimerE = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btnStart = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lblWordE = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 0));

        lblTimerE.setText("                       ");

        btnStart.setText("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnStartActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lblWordE.setText("                                                       ");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(134, 134, 134)
                .addComponent(lblTimerE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 243, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(btnStart)
                .addGap(58, 58, 58))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(196, 196, 196)
                .addComponent(lblWordE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 186, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addComponent(lblTimerE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(60, 60, 60)
                        .addComponent(btnStart)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 133, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(lblWordE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 91, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(54, 54, 54))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btnStartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        time.startTimer();


    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Easy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Easy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Easy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Easy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Easy().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    public javax.swing.JButton btnStart;
    public javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    public javax.swing.JLabel lblTimerE;
    public javax.swing.JLabel lblWordE;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

**Error**

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: variable lblTimerE
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Your `lblTimerE` variable doesn't exist inside the `newTimer` class (that should be called `NewTimer`, btw) --> you need to pass it as a parameter, or make it accessible through a getter

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code, and tweaked it a little: since you seem to need your JLabel inside the `NewTimer` class, I passed it as a constructor parameter. I didn't touch the rest of the code, since it's not part of the question.

```
    public class Easy extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        /**
         * @param args
         *           the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(final String args[]) {
            /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
            // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
            /*
             * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel. For details see
             * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
             */
            try {
                for (final javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (final ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Easy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (final InstantiationException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Easy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (final IllegalAccessException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Easy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (final javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Easy.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            // </editor-fold>

            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new Easy().setVisible(true));
        }

        NewTimer time;

        // Variables declaration - do not modify
        public javax.swing.JButton btnStart;

        public javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;

        public javax.swing.JLabel lblTimerE;

        public javax.swing.JLabel lblWordE;

        // End of variables declaration
        /**
         * Creates new form Easy
         */
        public Easy() {
            initComponents();
        }

        private void btnStartActionPerformed(final java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            // TODO add your handling code here:

            time.startTimer();

        }

        /**
         * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form. WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always regenerated by the Form
         * Editor.
         */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
        private void initComponents() {

            jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            lblTimerE = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            btnStart = new javax.swing.JButton();
            lblWordE = new javax.swing.JLabel();

            time = new NewTimer(lblTimerE);

            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // Rest of your code...
        }// </editor-fold>
    }

    public class NewTimer {
        JLabel lblTimerE;

        Timer timer = null;
        int counter = 5;
        int delay = 1500;

        public NewTimer(final JLabel lbl) {
            lblTimerE = lbl;
        }

        // method that will be called when the timer needs to start

        public void startTimer() {

            final ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {

                    if (counter == 0) {
                        timer.stop();

                        lblTimerE.setText("Time up");
                    } else {
                        lblTimerE.setText("Wait for " + counter + " sec");
                        counter--;
                    }
                }
            }; // end of action performed statement

            timer = new Timer(delay, action);
            timer.setInitialDelay(0);
            timer.start(); // this will start the timer

        } // end of method

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for help, as I'm using netbeans I'm unable to edit some parts of the code, mainly "time = new NewTimer(lblTimerE);". I will try some more, then start from scratch in a different way

Comment: Why aren't you able to edit parts of the code? It doesn't compile? (could be normal...)